# How to create stacked and grouped columns in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, stacked

I'd like to create a grouped, stacked column chart. There should be two columns (2000, 2050) for each region (OECD, BRICS, ...), and each of the columns has the same multiple categories. [Here is](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/megatrends/data/wasserbedarf.php) what I came up with so far.

The thing is that I have no idea how to display the "2000" and "2050"; as well as how to avoid that the categories are being displayed two times in the legend.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: This happens because you have two series with the same name, try to create only one serie for each one.

Comment: True indeed. I had to re-arrange categories, country names and values correctly. Then, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this (partly) by fiddling with the `showInLegend` and `legendItemClick`

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b72e0vh4/3/

[image]